# Problem with fraction display in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am making this `tikzpicture`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
ymin=0,
ymax=1,
xtick=data,
xticklabels={$1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$, $6$},
xlabel={Die Face},
ylabel={Probability},
title={Probability Distribution of a Six-Sided Die},
bar width=1pt, % Adjust the width of the bars
nodes near coords, % Display the explicit values near the bars
every node near coord/.append style={
  font=\footnotesize, 
  align=center, 
  anchor=west, 
  yshift=5pt, 
  /pgf/number format/.cd, 
  fixed, 
  fixed zerofill, 
  precision=1,
  frac
}, % Customize the appearance of the values
]
\addplot[fill=black!40,draw=black,line width=1pt] coordinates {
  (1, 1/6)
  (2, 1/6)
  (3, 1/6)
  (4, 1/6)
  (5, 1/6)
  (6, 1/6)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but the fractions are... well... displayed a little uglily. I honestly don't know where it's coming from...  I would just expect to have $\frac{1}{6}$, not this weird numerator and denominator.

Do you know how to solve this issue ?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:
Output:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
ymin=0,
ymax=1,
xtick=data,
xticklabels={$1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$, $6$},
xlabel={Die Face},
ylabel={Probability},
title={Probability Distribution of a Six-Sided Die},
bar width=1pt, % Adjust the width of the bars
nodes near coords, % Display the explicit values near the bars
every node near coord/.append style={
  font=\footnotesize, 
  align=center, 
  anchor=west, 
  yshift=7pt, % Adjust as needed
},
point meta=explicit symbolic % This line tells TikZ to use the provided labels directly
]

\addplot[fill=black!40,draw=black,line width=1pt] coordinates {
  (1, 1/6) [${\frac{1}{6}}$]
  (2, 1/6) [${\frac{1}{6}}$]
  (3, 1/6) [${\frac{1}{6}}$]
  (4, 1/6) [${\frac{1}{6}}$]
  (5, 1/6) [${\frac{1}{6}}$]
  (6, 1/6) [${\frac{1}{6}}$]
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I've added point `meta=explicit` symbolic to the axis options. This tells TikZ to use the labels provided in the square brackets `[...]` directly as they are.
The coordinates in the `\addplot command` now include explicit labels for each point in the format `[${\frac{1}{6}}$]`. These labels will be used directly as the node text, ensuring that the fractions display correctly as `\frac{1}{6}`.

Comment: This worked for me !

Answer (score 2):

You can use e.g. `frac shift=3`

The manual p. 1056

> **/pgf/number format/frac shift={⟨integer⟩}** (no default, initially 4)
>
> In
> case you experience problems because of stability problems, try
> experimenting with a differ- ent frac shift. Higher shift values k
> yield higher sensitivity to inaccurate data or inaccurate arithmetics.
> Technically, the following happens. If r < 1 is the fractional part of
> the mantissa, then a scale i = 1/r · 10k is computed where k is the
> shift; fractional parts of i are neglected. The value 1/r is computed
> internally, its error is amplified. If you still experience stability
> problems, use \usepackage{fp} in your preamble. The frac style will
> then automatically employ the higher absolute precision of fp for the
> computation of 1/r.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
ymin=0,
ymax=1,
xtick=data,
xticklabels={$1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$, $6$},
xlabel={Die Face},
ylabel={Probability},
title={Probability Distribution of a Six-Sided Die},
bar width=1pt, % Adjust the width of the bars
nodes near coords, % Display the explicit values near the bars
every node near coord/.append style={
  font=\footnotesize, 
  align=center, 
  anchor=west, 
  yshift=5pt, 
  /pgf/number format/.cd, 
  fixed, 
  fixed zerofill, 
  precision=1,
  frac,
  frac shift=3,
}, % Customize the appearance of the values
]
\addplot[fill=black!40, draw=black, line width=1pt] coordinates {
  (1, 1/6)
  (2, 1/6)
  (3, 1/6)
  (4, 1/6)
  (5, 1/6)
  (6, 1/6)
};
\end{axis}\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Bar graph with "1/6" labels on bars]

Comment: Then, it writes me 0.17... for which I wouldn't even need the frac option. For pedagogical  reasons, I don't want 0.17, I do want $\frac{1}{6}$...

Comment: @Javaccess: That is not what I get.

Comment: Ah ok, as an additional argument. I thought I had to put pgf/number format/frac shift=3

Comment: Yes that is correct, you have to put `pgf/number format/frac shift=3`